# How to combine variable with the rest of the command

Tags: powershell

How do I combine a variable with the rest of the command, without getting an error:

i.e. I want to issue:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity fred.bloggs@here.com:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

But using a variable $email for the email address. I tried:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $email:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

But this gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use braces to isolate the variable. Notice that with this syntax the variable name doesn't include the dollar sign:

```
"${email}:\Calendar"
```

Comment: No joy. + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (email:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptionCannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.

Comment: Does it help if you wrap it in double quotes? (e.g "${email}:\Calendar")

Answer (score 2):

The colon (`:`) is a valid character in variable names (it's a scope specifier or a PSDrive reference) and thus it looks for the variable `$email:` (which in itself is invalid, but still problematic here). You need either a subexpression and quotes:

```
"$($email):\Calendar"
```

or escape the colon:

```
$email`:\Calendar
```

Comment: Thanks but both of these are giving me 'The specified mailbox "test.user@here.com" doesn't exist.' It does.

Comment: The error is then somewhere else, your variable embedding/quoting problem is solved, however. Look further, then.

Comment: @Joey - just realized. You "ate" \ in your answer... :) Probably that's the reason for the error messages.

Comment: Aaah, that could be, indeed. Thanks. It might have disappeared when I changed the inline code to block code because Markdown doesn't really like `\`` as an escape character. Shay has the better answer, though; I tend to forget about `${...}` mostly because I rarely need it when golfing.

Comment: I did put the \ in even though you ate it. Didn't work anyway. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The variable wont expand unless its in double quotes:

```
set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$email:\Calendar" -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Comment: Thanks but I just tried your suggestion and got 'The specified mailbox "\Calendar" doesn't exist.'

Comment: finisterre: That's because `$email:` expands to nothing.